# Complément du nom avec « à »

Tags: grammaire, histoire, prépositions

Quelles sont les causes qui poussent certaines personnes à former le complément du nom avec la préposition *à* et non avec la préposition *de* comme dans l'exemple suivant ?

> La faute à Mathieu

Comment: C'est la faute à Hugo.

Comment: @Un francophone fait référence à: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gavroche#Biographie_du_personnage (en passant: cet usage est familier, voire incorrect)

Comment: @Unfrancophone: je pense que ton commentaire vaut bien une réponse.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Un [article](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article39) du site [langue-fr.net](http://langue-fr.net/) explique très bien d'ou provient cette "erreur" fréquente. Morceau choisi :

> Dire la robe à ma sœur n’est pas une une déformation populaire de
>   l’usage normé, mais le maintien, dans les parlers régionaux ou
>   populaires, d’un usage de l’ancien français remontant lui-même au bas
>   latin, Grevisse mentionne que :
>
> « La préposition à devant le complément déterminatif servait
>   aussi, par continuation d’un usage qui remonte au bas latin, à marquer
>   la possession : [...] Le fils AL rei Malcud ([Chanson de]
>   Rol[and], [vers] 1594.
>   « Il nous reste quelques traces de cette
>   construction, devenue provinciale ou très familière : la bête À bon
>   dieu, un fils À papa, sentir la vache À Colas (le protestantisme), la
>   vigne À mon oncle (une mauvaise excuse, une mauvaise défaite), c’est
>   un bon ami À moi. »

Grevisse indique aussi l'usage régulier avec un pronom personnel dans les cas où le déterminant possessif est exclus (une manière à lui, selon une thèse à moi, ...)

Answer (score 6):

Il semble que l'expression correcte soit "la faute de" + quelqu'un.

Cependant, on dit bien : "À qui la faute ?" et non pas "De qui la faute ?".

Hugo à aussi popularisé cette expression dans sa chanson de Gavroche:

> Je suis tombé par terre
>
> C'est la faute à Voltaire
>
> Le nez dans le ruisseau
>
> C'est la faute à Rousseau

L'expression apparaìt aussi ici :

> Mon capitaine... C'est de la faute à la mairerie. Moi, j'leur disais pour la permission; eux ils m'ont dit qu'ça f'sait rien (BENJAMIN, Gaspard, 1915, p. 127) :

L'expression "La faute en est à X" existe aussi.

> La faute en est à la poste, sans doute (FLAUB., Corresp., 1871, p. 247)

En revanche "on ne fait pas faute de quelque chose". Ou encore: "Et le combat cessa faute de combattants." (Corneille).

Comment: En tout cas, ça me rassure de voir l'évolution de la poste depuis 1871...

Answer (score 5):

J'ai perdu tout mes mots,

C'est la faute à Hugo,

Que ma grammaire faillisse

C'est la faute à Grevisse.