# Le chien de ma mère vs. la faute à qui

Tags: grammaire

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Complément du nom avec « à »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/763/complement-du-nom-avec-a)

Je me suis retrouvé tout confus après avoir expliqué à un étranger que l’on devait dire « le chien **de** ma mère » et m’être entendu rétorquer « oui mais on dit bien : c’est la faute **à** Voltaire ».

Quelle est la règle juste ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Il me semble que « c'est la faute **à** Voltaire » est en fait une faute de français, certes utilisée voire popularisée par Victor Hugo dans les Misérables (la célèbre chanson de Gavroche), mais cela reste une faute, l'expression correcte étant « c'est la faute **de** Voltaire ».

> La préposition à est incorrecte au sein d’un complément de
>   détermination (la voiture à Raoul). Mais elle est possible et même
>   obligatoire au sein d’autres tournures syntaxiques (cette voiture est
>   à Raoul). Et elle est également de mise devant un pronom (à qui la
>   faute ? il a un style à lui…).

---

> La tournure incriminée est présente dans un français populaire assez
>   ancien, de sorte qu’elle s’est gardée dans quelques expressions figées
>   : on a volé (la bague à Jules, une bête à bon dieu) voire
>   hypochoristiques (un fils à Papa, un chienchien à sa mémère…).

[Référence](http://www.chilton.com/paq/archive/PAQ-01-040.html)