# C'est la faute à/de Voltaire ou C'est de la faute à/de Voltaire

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

- I am puzzled what is the correct version.

> C'est la faute *à*/*de* Voltaire.

ou

> C'est de la faute à/de Voltaire.

- Also, how this turn can be used in real context?
- I know it is an old turn. Can it still be used colloquially and be understood?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complément du nom avec « à »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/763/compl%c3%a9ment-du-nom-avec-%c3%a0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct actual French sentence would be `C'est de la faute de Voltaire`,

However, `C'est la faute à Voltaire` is [a really famous reference](https://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2017/09/26/37003-20170926ARTFIG00008-c-est-la-faute-a-ne-faites-plus-l-erreur.php) from **Les Misérables**.

It's an understandable sentence, even if not correct.

You could use it when you stumble and fall for example, to quote **Victor Hugo** saying :

```
Je suis tombé par terre, 
C'est la faute à Voltaire
```

You might also use it when asked if you know who's the culprit :

```
- De qui est-ce la faute ?
- C'est la faute à Voltaire
```

Using the reference would be an obvious way of saying you don't know.